# Passing cars on the right, and later merging into their lane

Tags: safety, commuter, traffic, etiquette

My commute takes me along a fairly busy road, with 4 lanes of traffic and parked cars along most of it. There are no bike lanes, but in some places, it's wide enough that I can easily pass traffic on the right (which is [legal](http://www.malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXIV/Chapter85/Section11b) in my state, as far as I can tell), and in some places, there's actually a whole extra lane on the right for a block or two. However, the conditions change from block to block. On some of the blocks, there is not enough room to pass safely on the right of cars, and there are some places where the extra lane on the right no longer exists across the intersection or is filled with parked cars.

There are several times when I've passed cars on the right, either in a full lane or in the room between a lane of stopped cars and parked cars, and then realized after crossing through the next intersection that I need to merge back into the next lane. What is the etiquette of merging back into the next lane in such circumstances?

There are a few possibilities that I've tried, and all of them seem unsatisfying in certain ways.

1. Continue to travel in the lane that will run out until it actually does, then stop and wait for a gap in the traffic before merging in. That can sometimes require stopping and waiting for quite a while, due to busy traffic.
2. Signal to the left in advance of running out of the lane, check for a reasonable gap in the cars while still moving, and merge into that gap once I've determined it's safe, or fall back to the first option if that doesn't work. The problem is, this requires a good deal of judgement to tell when there's a good enough gap in traffic to merge back in, I can only glance back quickly and not make good eye contact with drivers in the lane I'm merging into since I need to be paying attention to what's ahead of me as well, and I'm not sure if I'm cutting people off too closely.
3. Pass the cars on the right, then pull up in front of them at a stop light so I can take the lane when it turns green. This makes me feel like a jerk, like I'm cutting in line.
4. Simply stay in, and take, the lane that doesn't keep disappearing. This is what I would do if I were driving a car. The problems are that I get stuck in stop-and-go traffic which slows me down, I have to breathe in the smog of trucks and busses in front of me as I wait, and I hold up somewhat more traffic as I don't take several of the block-long opportunities to make it easy for cars to pass me.
5. Run red lights. This way, I can actually get into the lane I need to before I have to contend with cars. The disadvantage is, of course, that I'm running red lights.

Comment: "Nothing in this clause shall relieve a bicyclist of the duty to facilitate overtaking as required by section 2 of chapter 89. "  Is it legal to pass on the right in a car in MA? If not, its not legal for you to do so as a cyclist either.

Comment: @Andy "Every person operating a bicycle upon a way ...shall be subject to the traffic laws and regulations of the commonwealth and the special regulations contained in this section, except that: (1) the bicycle operator may keep to the right when passing a motor vehicle which is moving in the travel lane of the way"; that seems to state pretty clearly that bicycles are allowed to do it even when cars are not. The section you quoted states the cyclists must facilitate overtaking, just like slow driving cars, but that applies to when car traffic is moving faster than bike traffic.

Comment: "There are several times when I've passed cars on the right, either in a full lane or in the room between a lane of stopped cars and parked cars" and "the bicycle operator may keep to the right when passing a motor vehicle which is *moving* in the travel lane of the way".  You cannot pass stopped cars on the right, which is the basis of your question.  "What is the etiquette of merging back into the next lane in such circumstances [when I] realized after crossing through the next intersection that I need to merge back into the next lane."

Comment: @Andy If you are in a car, there are two lanes, and the left lane is full of stopped cars, would you stop before that to avoid passing stopped cars on the right? Why would being on a bicycle suddenly make you do that? It's always legal to pass stopped cars on the right, the exemption for bicycles is to allow them to pass moving cars on the right in places where it's safe to do so.

Comment: I should probably clarify that it's not *always* legal, but legal if there is an appropriate lane and you are not passing a car that is stopping for a pedestrian. It would be quite silly to disallow any passing on the right of stopped cars, as it would mean that when the left lane filled up at a stop light before the right lane did, people in the right lane would have to suddenly stop and leave large gaps in order to avoid passing on the right. I can't imagine anyone would believe that that's how you interpret the prohibition on passing on the right.

Comment: I don't understand where we are not communicating.  You're not in another lane, you're on the shoulder, so your contention about the left lane is irrelevant.  Think of it this way; would a motorcycle be allowed to ride between stopped cars in the right most lane and parked cars?  The answer is no, it would be illegal. The exception you quoted means that you may overtake (pass) a car in a single lane on the right instead of left (whereas a car would have to overtake only on the right).  The goal seems to be to keep cycles to the right as much as possible.  It doesn't mean you can ...

Comment: ... jump to the front of a line of stopped cars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18457/discussion-between-brian-campbell-and-andy).

Comment: @Andy This discussion is getting increasingly off topic from my question, so I've opted to use the feature to migrate the discussion to chat, if you would like to continue this discussion.

Comment: Not really; re-read the law again, I think you'll see its about overtaking a car, not carte blanch to pass on the right no matter what.  Your question is what to do when you get yourself into a certain situation, and i'm basically saying follow the law and you won't end up in that situation as much to begin with.

Comment: @Andy The comments on a question are meant for quick clarifications or questions, not intended for extended discussion. I moved the discussion to chat to avoid cluttering up this discussion (as well as allow more room for clarification). Did you see the chat and more extended discussion of the issue that I posted there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems to me that **your best option is choice 2: Signal to the left in advance of running out of the lane, check for a reasonable gap in the cars while still moving, and merge into that gap once you've determined that it's safe.**

In that option you are essentially behaving like exactly what you are - a slow moving vehicle.  Your behavior is like what you would expect if you were operating a tractor, or a horse-drawn carriage.  You operate in the lane when neccessary, move over to the right to allow others to pass when safe and convenient, and carefully merge back into the traffic lane when the shoulder is no longer safe.

While doing this you want to avoid weaving in and out of traffic every few feet.

This is also similar and predictable behavior much like what you need to do when the shoulder runs out as a right-turn only lane blocks your path.

Option 1 is unsatisfactory because you lose momentum and will have a difficult time merging.

Option 3 is a poor choice, not from the issue of passing cars on the right (which while legal in many areas, is dangerous), but because it's rude and then forces cars to pass you later - playing leapfrog.

Option 4 is a possibility, but then again, think about operating a 'slow moving vehicle.'  If you are consistently the same speed as motorists, you may stay in the lane, particularly if the shoulder is unsafe, otherwise, move over and let them pass.

Option 5 is the poorest choice.  You may be able to cross against the light safely, but not only is it risky, it makes you a poor ambassador of cycling, causing motorists to be angry at other cyclist, and frequently puts you back in the leapfrog situation.  Plus, you could get a ticket, at least in my town.

Comment: I agree, option 2 is the least-bad choice. I would also be extremely hesitant to ride on a road like this regularly; I would consider a mirror mandatory equipment in this kind of traffic.

Comment: @neilfein Absolutely. I use one of the mirrors that mounts on my glasses, I find I prefer it to handlebar mounted mirrors. I keep tabs on traffic with the mirror, once I see a gap I signal, and then I physically turn to check to make sure the gap is really there. This is pretty much the only way to get to work; I need to cross a river, and there aren't that many bridges to choose from. This is the least-bad route of all. I tend to lean towards option 2 as well, but I've been experimenting with the other options to see if any of them work any better.

Comment: I agree, basically 2. I also use 3 all the time (usual and expected in the Netherlands due to the bicycle-adjusted road layout). It gives you a few seconds to get up to speed and stability before moving over to let the cars pass you, since speed differences are probably the major safety issue in being overtaken. I don't think it's rude at all, since you're not staying in front. 4 is the *really* rude option, holding up everyone. 5 is nice if you're suicidal ... ;)

Comment: I'd say option 1 is required if you can't safely merge before the lane runs out and is also what a car would do. Losing momentum is not a reason for a cyclist to do something any more than it would be a reason for a car.  You should probably also note that option 5 would be illegal (and cyclists have been ticketed for running red lights where I live, AND they got points on their driver's license as well).

Answer (score 4):

I used to pass on the right but have started to see the benefits of using option 4 (stay in the lane) whenever possible.  It can be a bit slower, but by keeping your lane position you stay highly visible to drivers around you, don't have to worry about merging or losing your place, and run less risk of getting "right hooked" by someone turning right.

I'll only move over to the right if it's a proper lane (i.e. no parked cars and not a right turning lane) or to let cars pass me if I know I can get back in easily.  If the lane you're riding in ends, then option 2 (signal then merge when safe) is the way to go.

Of course if you're on a busy road or highway and there's a decent shoulder, then by all means use it instead of the lane.